# How to get scrollView.keyboardDismissMode delegate?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know when the tableView was actually dragged without adding any gesture recognizers. (I already have too many gesture recognizers)

```
self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableview inherits from UIScrollView, so you can use the scrollview  delegate UIScrollViewDelegate to see when the user starts dragging. This delegate will be set up if you have set the tableView delegate to your ViewController. The method to use is scrollViewWillBeginDragging